# mouse picking a rotating sprite in an Xna game

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, xna, rotation, mouse

I am working on a simple game where you click on square sprites before they disappear.  I decided to get fancy and make the squares rotate.  Now, when I click on the squares, they don't always respond to the click.  I think that I need to rotate the click position around the center of the rectangle(square) but I am not sure how to do this.  Here is my code for the mouse click:

```
    if ((mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed) &&
    (currentSquare.Contains(mouse.X , mouse.Y )))
```

And here is the rotation logic:

```
    float elapsed = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

        RotationAngle += elapsed;
        float circle = MathHelper.Pi * 2;
        RotationAngle = RotationAngle % circle;
```

I am new to Xna and programming in general, so any help is appreciated.

Thanks a lot,

Bill

Answer (score 1):

So you're trying to determine if a point is in a rectangle, but when the rectangle is rotated?

The Contains() method will only work if the current rotation is 0 (I guess currentSquare is a rectangle representing the image position without rotation?).

What you will have to do is do the **opposite rotation** of the image on the mouse coordinates (the mouse coordinates should rotate around the origin of your image), then calculate if the new position is within currentSquare. You should be able to do all of this using vectors.
(Untested)

```
bool MouseWithinRotatedRectangle(Rectangle area, Vector2 tmp_mousePosition, float angleRotation)
{
    Vector2 mousePosition = tmp_mousePosition - currentSquare.Origin;
    float mouseOriginalAngle = (float)Math.Atan(mousePosition.Y / mousePosition.X);
    mousePosition = new Vector2((float)(Math.Cos(-angleRotation + mouseOriginalAngle) * mousePosition.Length()), 
                                (float)(Math.Sin(-angleRotation + mouseOriginalAngle) * , mousePosition.Length()));
    return area.Contains(mousePosition);
}
```

Comment: Hello again, I am still a bit lost. Here is my Game.cs file: pastebin.com/b4T3bKT3 I am having trouble figuring out how to use the code you guys showed me.

Comment: hello again, are you still coming on stack overflow?  I want to ask you some more things about this problem

Comment: i have posted my code on github, please feel free to add your code so I can understand how it works.  https://github.com/tertl2/squarechase_modded

Answer (score 1):

If you dont need pixel pefect detection you can create bounding sphere for each piece like this.

```
        var PieceSphere = new BoundingSphere()
                         {
                             Center =new Vector3(new Vector2(Position.X + Width/2, Position.Y + Height/2), 0f),
                             Radius = Width / 2
                         };
```

Then create another bounding sphere around mouse pointer.For position use mouse coordinates and for radius 1f. Because mouse pointer will be moving it will change its coordinates so you have to also update the sphere's center on each update.

Checking for clicks would be realy simple then.

```
foreach( Piece p in AllPieces )
{
    if ((mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed) && p.BoundingSphere.Intersects(MouseBoundingSphere))
    {
        //Do stuff 
    }
}
```

Comment: i am trying to implement this and I am having a hard time.  https://github.com/tertl2/squarechase_modded if you have a minute, can you place your above code into the github and commit it.  I dont understand why I need a bounding sphere for the mouse pointer?

Comment: what are the Position.X, Width, etc... are those new variables or are they the position of the squares?

Comment: sorry to keep asking, but what is AllPieces?  I think I am almost getting it working.. :)  I just need a little help :)

Comment: Ok i just forked your repository and took a quick look at your code.

Comment: I'll change a thing or two and commit probably tomorrow.

Comment: merged and thank you.  there is another version up that is working now, it is version 1.1, but I want to implement some of you ideas too.  I noticed that some of my code is redundant.  Feel free to play around with it if want.  It is a learning experience for me.

Comment: well, I've been messing with what you gave me and I like how you cleaned it up, but how can I make rectangles change position even every 2s or so?  ALso, how do you recommend fixing the mouse click issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you are lazy like me you could just do a circular distance check.

Assuming mouse and box.center are Vector2

```
#gets us C^2 according to the pythagorean Theorem
var radius = (box.width / 2).squared() + (box.height / 2).square 

#distance check
(mouse - box.center).LengthSquared() < radius
```

Not perfectly accurate but the user would have a hard time noticing and inaccuracies that leave a hitbox slightly too large are always forgiven. Not to mention the check is incredibly fast just calculate the radius when the square is created.

Comment: Hello again, I am still a bit lost.  Here is my Game.cs file: http://pastebin.com/b4T3bKT3 I am having trouble figuring out how to use the code you guys showed me.